# I can not display data into input Text

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am receiving Json data via Ajax but the problem is that I cannot display data into input Text and every things work fine any one can help please

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
       function getProblemById(Id) {
            var Id = Id;
            

            $.ajax({
                url: "/BarnoProblems/getById?Id=" + Id,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    
           $('#Discrptions').val( data.Discrption);//here is the problem
                   
                   

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("erorr");
                }
                
            });


        }
 


    </script>
```

this is my C# and it is work fine

```
    public JsonResult getById(int  Id){

        var pro = from pr in db.BarnoProblems
                  join br in db.Branches
                  on pr.BranchId equals br.Id
                  where pr.Id == Id
                  select new
                  {
                      pr.Id,
                      pr.Discrption,
                      pr.ProblemImage,
                      pr.ProblemType,
                      pr.Source,
                      pr.statute,
                      pr.comment,
                      barnchname = br.Name,
                      citys = pr.Branch.City.Name

                  };

        return Json(pro.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: this is how you would return json response from your backend `return Json(new { Discrption = "your description." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Comment: i am receiving all the data but i cant display the value into input text

Comment: Its because you are receiving  a list. you cannot assign a list to input box.

Comment: does your list contain `Discription` key pair value ? if yes then try this: `if(data.length > 0) $('#Discrptions').val(value1 = data[0].Discrption); `

Comment: thanks man worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function(data){
  if(data.length > 0) 
       $('#Discrptions').val(data[0].Discrption);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code, I'm assuming the thing you are hung up on is the way you are processing the data. It should look like this:

`data['Discrption']`

Comment: Is there any difference between `data[key]` and `data.key`?

Comment: still not displaying int input text